# ¿Por qué mi programa echo en java con conexión a mysql hace las búsquedas muy lento?

Tags: java, mysql

Realice un sistema que tiene conexión a una base de datos en mi pc corre muy bien el programa hace las búsquedas en una tabla con conexión a la base de datos muy rápido pero cuando ejecuto mi programa en otra pc que esta conectada a mi base de datos las búsquedas en la tabla las hace muy lentas.

Comment: Armando, bienvenido a SOes. Te invitamos a hacer el [tour]. Tu pregunta es demasiada amplia y podria ser puesta en espera o cerrada. Considera leer el articulo [ask] y despues volver y [edit] tu pregunta para que sea aceptable.